# Code seems to continue running after return statement (in C)

Tags: c, algorithm, return

I am trying to create a binary search algorithm and have used two sets of if statements for when the sample is even/uneven. The uneven side currently works as planned and returns true, the even side returns true but then goes to the "catch all" piece of code at the bottom of the function and returns false:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    //searching algorithm
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //searching algorithm where n is even, if b is not the searched for value, split the sample and run recursively until value is equal to b or n<=0
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        int starte = n / 2;
        eprintf("starte is %i", starte);
        int startpluse = starte + 1;
        int b = values[starte];
        eprintf("b is %i", b);
        //for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        //printf("%i,",values[i]);}
        if (b == value)
        {
            printf("true\n");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (value > b)
            {
                int o = starte - 1;
                int searcharrayc[o];
                for (int h = startpluse, l = 0; l < o; h++, l++)
                {
                    searcharrayc[l] = values[h];
                }
                search(value, searcharrayc, o);
            }
            if (value < b)
            {
                int searcharrayd[starte];
                for (int m = 0; m < starte; m++)
                {
                    searcharrayd[m] = values[m];
                }
                search(value, searcharrayd, starte);
            }
        }
    }
    //searching algorithm where n is uneven, if a is not the searched for value, split the sample and run recursively until a is equal to the value or n<=0 
    if (n % 2 == 1)
    {
        eprintf("n is %i", n);
        int start = (n / 2) - 0.5;
        int startplus = start + 1;
        int a = values[start];
        eprintf("a is %i", a);
        if (a == value)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (value > a)
            {
                int searcharray[start];
                for (int i = startplus, j = 0; j < start; i++, j++)
                {
                    searcharray[j] = values[i];
                    eprintf("i is %i", i);
                }
                search(value, searcharray, start);
            }
            if (value < a)
            {
                int searcharrayb[start];
                for (int k = 0; k < start; k++)
                {
                    searcharrayb[k] = values[k];
                    eprintf("k is %i", k);
                }
                search(value, searcharrayb, start);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: When you make a new call to search() you should use return search()

Comment: `if` statement is unnecessary. You have to determine the ranges on which it will work. parity doesn't comes into picture here.

Comment: Of course it does. The program resumes from the call stack. Once             `search(value, searcharray, start);` is done evaluating it will continue down your program. Thus `return false;` is executed.

Comment: You should not use a variable named `l`, it is hard to see a difference to `1`.

Comment: I have changed that section of the code that runs the recursion to the following: `if (search(value, searcharray, start)== true){
                 return true;
             }else{
                 return false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like this:

```
search(...)
{ 
    if(cond)
        return false
    if(cond)
        return true
    else
        search(...)
    return false
}
```

You need to change it to:

```
search(...)
{ 
    if(cond)
        return false
    if(cond)
        return true
    else
        return search(...)
}
```

Note the extra return before the recursive call to search